# Incorrect Range Height - Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am currently trying to get grab values from another spreadsheet and then paste it into a destination spreadsheet. The problem I am running into is that I am getting incorrect range height and incorrect range widths when I run this code. I read something about 2d arrays but I believe I already have a 2d array here to paste to the spreadsheet. Thank you for your time.

```
function GmailToDrive_StaticTest(gmailSubject, importFileID){


 var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:' + gmailSubject + ' -label:uploaded has:attachment'); // performs Gmail query for email threads

 for (var i in threads){
      var messages = threads[i].getMessages(); // finds all messages of threads returned by the query

      for (var j in messages){
           var attachments = messages[j].getAttachments(); // finds all attachments of found messages
           var timestamp = messages[j].getDate(); // receives timestamp of each found message
           var timestampMinusOne = new Date(timestamp.getTime() - (86400000)); // sets the received timestamp to exactly one day prior (# in milliseconds)
           var date = Utilities.formatDate(timestampMinusOne, "MST", "yyyy-MM-dd"); // cleans the timestamp string

           for (var k in attachments){
                var blobs = {
                      dataType: attachments[k].getContentType(), // retrives the file types of the attachments
                      data: attachments[k].copyBlob(), // creates blob files for every attachment
                      fileName: attachments[k].getName()
                      };

                var tempFile = DriveApp.createFile(blobs.data.setContentType('text/csv')).setName(blobs.fileName.split("-", 1).toString() + date); // creates csv files in drive's root per blob file

                var tempFileConverted = Drive.Files.copy( {}, tempFile.getId(), {convert: true} ); // converts created files to gsheets
                var importData = {
                      file: tempFileConverted,
                      ID: tempFileConverted.getId(),
                      Sheet1: SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFileConverted.getId() ).getActiveSheet(),
                      Sheet1_Values: SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFileConverted.getId() ).getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
                      };

                tempFile.setTrashed(true);

                var importData_Sheet1_Rows = importData.Sheet1.getMaxRows(); - 2;
                var importData_Sheet1_Columns = importData.Sheet1.getMaxColumns(); - 2;
                var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(importFileID).getSheets()[0]; 

                destSheet.clearContents();
                Logger.log(importData.Sheet1_Values)
                destSheet.getRange(1, 1, importData_Sheet1_Rows, importData_Sheet1_Columns).setValues(importData.Sheet1_Values);
                DriveApp.getFileById(importData.ID).setTrashed(true);    


           }
      }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMaxRows()` and `getMaxColumns()` return the maximum number of column and rows in a sheet, while `getDataRange().getValues()` return all the values in a sheet **that contain data** .

So, unless all the cells in a sheet have data the dimensions won't match !

The best you could do is to get the actual size of the data array and use that to set the range for the values in the destination sheet.

It goes (more) simply like this :

```
destSheet.getRange(1, 1, importData.Sheet1_Values.length, importData.Sheet1_Values[0].length).setValues(importData.Sheet1_Values);
```

you don't need the other values for rows and columns, just ignore that in your script.

Comment: Or use `getLastRow()` and `getLastColumn()` which match the range retrieved by `getDataRange`.

Comment: You're right of course but I preferred to focus on the pure array approach because I think it is more universal, any 2d array will be useable like this, whatever it is made of and wherever you paste the values. Anyway I should have include that in the answer so thank you for the additional information you provided.